# Is it possible to compute the forest area around each pixel in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an asset of land use. The values of the pixel between 40 and 45 correspond to forest.

I would like to compute for each pixel of the image the forest area in square kilometers in a radius of 30km.

This an example for `Brazil`

```
var brazil = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Brazil'));
  
var roi = brazil.geometry();

var image = ee.Image('myAsset').clip(roi);
var band = image.select('b1'); 

// Define the radius in meters
var radius = 30000;

// Create a kernel with the specified radius
var kernel = ee.Kernel.circle(radius, 'meters');

// Create a binary mask for pixels with values between 40 and 45
var mask = band.gte(40).and(band.lte(45));

var area = mask.reduceNeighborhood({
              reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
              kernel: kernel
           }).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1000000);
           
           
// Rename the band to 'area'
area = area.rename('area');
```

Am I missing something?